# Can't port bind a docker windows container to localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose

usually I run docker linux containers, but unfortunately I have to run docker windows containers for a current project (I'm using a windows machine). I can't do a port binding to localhost, because if I try, I get this error message:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint mongodb on network test_stuff: Windows does not support host IP addresses in NAT settings
```

My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    mongodb:
        image : mongo:4.4.4
        container_name: mongodb
        ports:
        - 127.0.0.1:27016:27017
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

This exact same file works perfectly fine on linux containers. It works if I remove "127.0.0.1" but it binds to 0.0.0.0.
Then I still can't access the database via localhost but my host port is exposed.

Do you know a fix for this, that does not ruin my docker settings when I can switch back to linux containers?